# "@" added to every line where INDIRECT formula is used

Tags: excel

In my workbook, I have connected many sheets and sometimes have to use the INDIRECT function. Today Excel started to add "@" in front of each INDIRECT function and the tables stopped working. Is it caused by an update?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34

Comment: Thanks, this description I was looking for. All sheets are working fine again, not sure where was the trouble that it didn´t work for some time.